# How to update multiple input fields using data class in Android composable function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have Composable function that represents address form with 9 input fields. I don't want to add 9 parameters for values and 9 parameters for every onTextChange. So I decided to create CustomerAddress data class.

```kotlin
data class CustomerAddress(
    val postalCode: String = "",
    val postOffice: String = "",
    val city: String = "",
    val street: String = "",
    val buildingNumber: String = "",
    val locumNumber: String = "",
    val commune: String = "",
    val poviat: String = "",
    val voivodeship: String = ""
)
```

I pass class object as initialValues and callback to run validations and save.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun EditAddressForm(initValues: CustomerAddress, isError:Boolean = false, onSave: (CustomerAddress) -> Unit) {
    var postalCode by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.postalCode) }
    var postOffice by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.postOffice) }
    var city by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.city) }
    var street by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.street) }
    var buildingNumber by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.buildingNumber) }
    var locumNumber by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.locumNumber) }
    var commune by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.commune) }
    var poviat by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.poviat) }
    var voivodeship by remember { mutableStateOf(initValues.voivodeship) }
// more code..

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {

        if(isError){
            Text(text = "Error!")
        }
// ....
```

**For simplification**
When validation failed I set field value to "###" and isError to true. Then I can see Error message, but fields values not updating.
In validations I always return new coppy of class, ex. initialValues.coppy(postCode: "###").

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

I tried with LaunchedEffect and it is working, but I don't think it is good for this kind of usecase.

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(initValues){
    postalCode = initValues.postalCode
//...
}
```

---

I used your tips, but now composable recomposes ALL fields without skip.

[image]

Comment: To achieve what you describe I'd advise you to turn this component into a stateless one (remove all of the remembered values and step away from passing "initValues" in favor of "values"). Manage field updates inside the ViewModel (or equivalent) by updating the "CustomerAddress" there. Look up "state hoisting term" for concrete examples.

Comment: Then my composable function need to have 9 values and 9 onTextchange callbacks. Is is not to many?

Comment: @MieszkoKoźma imagine that this composable is used in many places. So I should provide lot of code duplication to handle changes. Mayby sapareted VM for it?

Comment: It would reflect exactly what it does, IMHO it's okay. If you care about the number of arguments you can approach it in many ways. For example, having fields represented by a sealed class with a "value" field, then you'd have a need for only one lambda passed to the composable. You can also pass a ViewModel directly to this composable and call its update methods directly from there. It's always a tradeoff in the end. Think if it's worth covering "if you were to reuse this" scenarios in your specific case, done is better than perfect.

Comment: I used your tip. But now on every type, it recompose all form (all fields are recreated) before only one was edited.  Look at updated post

Comment: Might be an issue with lambdas being passed. Even if they don't change they might trigger recompositions. I recommend you check out this article that'll help you understand the issue better and find possible solutions. https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2022/08/05/jetpack-compose-recomposition/

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code. You don't need to remember all the fields, just remember the `customerAddress` and update it with something like `myAddress = newValue` to trigger the recomposition.

Something like:

```
var myAddress by remember {
    mutableStateOf(CustomerAddress())
}

AddressUI(
    myAddress = myAddress,
    onUpdatePostalCode = {
        myAddress = myAddress.copy(postalCode = it)
   }
)
```

with:

```
@Composable
fun AddressUI(
    myAddress: CustomerAddress,
    onUpdatePostalCode: (String) -> Unit
){

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(myAddress.postalCode) }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            onUpdatePostalCode(it)
        }
    )

}
```

Better to move all the update logic in a `ViewModel`.

Comment: I tried it, but when I pass new CustomerAddress object, it not detect it was changed. I want use this composable function to Create and Edit Address. So it is important to receive Address from outside. Not declare it inline, as you show.

Comment: @mateo It is not the problem, the logic is the same. You just need to remember 1 variable (the `address`) and update it with `myAddress = myAddress.copy(postalCode = it)`

Comment: Edited snipped force recomposition on each element on every type. Before when I use remember values typing was on only one filed.

Comment: @mateo It is just an example how to update the myAddress value. Move the validation/update as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It will be always a better practice to provide these ui states from a viewmodel with a data class.

Example

```
data class AddressUiState(  
 val postalCode: String = "",
 val postOffice: String = "",
 val city: String = "",
 val street: String = "",
 val buildingNumber: String = "",
 val locumNumber: String = "",
 val commune: String = "",
 val poviat: String = "",
 val voivodeship: String = "")
```

Then in your viewmodel you provide the state and change only what you need

```
class YourViewModel(): ViewModel() {
  
      var uiState = mutableStateOf(AddressUiState())
        private set
  
     fun onStreetChange(newValue: String) {
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(street = newValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: So I need to create 9 callbacks for each field in viewModel and pass it to Composable? In my code CustomerAddress comming from VM as StateFlow<CustomerAddress?>.

Comment: nope, you only pass the uiState into your composable and access its value, every time one change, that only part in the composable will change

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this project. I have handle this `State` and `Validations` in compose-friendly way, Also it supports enormous changes in the UI.

Its a clean and minimal architecture can follow in many project, which contain similar like UI's, if it need 10 or more Input box it can easily adaptable.

https://github.com/habituer/AddressSaver

[image]

Let me brief my answer....

UI will contain all the stuffs to build the address components,
example

```
data class UI(
    val postalCode: PostalCode = PostalCode(),
    val postOffice: PostOffice = PostOffice(),
    val city: City = City(),
    val street: Street = Street(),
    val poviat: Poviat = Poviat(),
    val commune: Commune = Commune(),
    val buildingNumber: BuildingNumber = BuildingNumber(),
    val voivodeship: Voivodeship = Voivodeship(),
    val locumNumber: LocumNumber = LocumNumber(),
)
```

for example `PostalCode` class will contain something like...

```
data class PostalCode(
    val postalCode: String = "",
    val postalCodeLabel: String = defaultPostalCodeLabel,
    val postalCodeLength: Int = 6,
    val postalCodeKeyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
    val hasPostalCodeValidationError: Boolean = false,
)
```

All the ui related need to hold inside this class, so we can increase the scope if needed.

```
class CustomerAddressVM @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

   
    var uiState = mutableStateOf(UI())
        private set

    init {
        val initialValue = "678507"
        val postalCode = uiState.value.postalCode.copy(postalCode = initialValue)
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(postalCode = postalCode)
    }

    fun initValues(cityString: String) {
        val city = uiState.value.city.copy(city = cityString)
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(city = city)
    }

    val validationEvent = MutableSharedFlow<UIEvent.ValidationEvent>()

    /**
     * This method will trigger on user interactions and the impact will be state change of the ui.
     */
    fun onEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is UIEvent.PostalCodeChanged -> {
                val postalCode =
                    uiState.value.postalCode.copy(postalCode = event.postalCode)
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(postalCode = postalCode)
            }

            is UIEvent.PostOfficeChanged -> {
                val postOffice = uiState.value.postOffice.copy(postOffice = event.postOffice)
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(postOffice = postOffice)
            }

            is UIEvent.CityChanged -> {
                val city = uiState.value.city.copy(city = event.city)
                uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(city = city)
            }

            is UIEvent.Submit -> {
                validateInputs()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun validateInputs() {
        val postalCodeResult = Validator.validatePostalCode(uiState.value.postalCode)
        val postalCode =
            uiState.value.postalCode.copy(hasPostalCodeValidationError = !postalCodeResult.status)
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(postalCode = postalCode)

        val postOfficeResult = Validator.validatePostOffice(uiState.value.postOffice)

        val postOffice =
            uiState.value.postOffice.copy(hasPostOfficeValidationError = !postOfficeResult.status)
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(postOffice = postOffice)

        val cityResult = Validator.validateCity(uiState.value.city)
        val city =
            uiState.value.city.copy(hasCityValidationError = !cityResult.status)
        uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(city = city)

        val hasError = listOf(
            postalCodeResult,
            postOfficeResult,
            cityResult,
        ).any { !it.status }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (!hasError) {
                validationEvent.emit(UIEvent.ValidationEvent.Success(msg = SuccessMessageValidation))
            } else {
                validationEvent.emit(UIEvent.ValidationEvent.Failure(msg = ErrorMessageValidation))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is easy to interact with the VM code like this.

```
 AddressUIComponent(
                    postalCode,
                    onTextChanged = {
                        customerAddressViewModel.onEvent(UIEvent.PostalCodeChanged(it))
                    },
                    isError = postalCode.hasPostalCodeValidationError,
                    onNext = {
                        localFocus.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                    },
                    onDone = {
                    },
                )
```

UIEvent can contain the Events need to interact with editables.

`AddressComponent` is custom composable to hold the `OutlinedTextField`

```
@Composable
fun AddressUIComponent(
    componentProps: ComponentProps,
    imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Next,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onNext: (KeyboardActionScope) -> Unit,
    onDone: (KeyboardActionScope) -> Unit,
) {
     var text by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(componentProps.value)
    }
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            onTextChanged(it)
        },
        label = {
            Text(componentProps.label)
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = componentProps.keyboardType,
            imeAction = imeAction,
            capitalization = componentProps.keyboardCapitalization,
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = onDone,
            onNext = onNext,
        ),
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        ),
        isError = isError,
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed example. Tell me how to fill AddressUIComponent with data, for edit purpose. AddressUIComponent.kt#L30-L32  you have local text state, but I can't get how to set initial value. You never use componentProps.value. When you change rememberSaveable  to {mutableStateOf(componentProps.value)} You have the same code as I provided. No option to modify remembered text value in composition (only in LaunchedEffect). After some answers I'll make some improvements and give an update on it.

Comment: @mateo oh for initializing you have modify the VM. `init { }` and also you have to change the AddressComponent `mutableStateOf(componentProps.value)`. I have edited my code for initialization purpose please check above